# SPSS don't see MSSQL-view

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-connection, spss

I Connect SPSS 20.0.0 via ODBC to MSSQL server 2008. But now it has stopped displaying New views I create in the database. It displays all views I have created earlier. But New ones? No! Excel and MsAccess have no problems using the same ODBC Connection. I am a bit stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [SPSS documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/spssmodl/v15r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.spss.modeler.help/dbconnectionsdialog.htm), it might be helpful to go to the Database Connections dialog and click the **Refresh** button.